# Group result in MySQL and show on list

Tags: php, mysql

I have a large table:

```
create table data
(
    id                bigint unsigned auto_increment primary key,
    first              varchar(120)                     null,
    last_           varchar(120)                     null,
    country             varchar(30)                     not null
)
    collate = utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

I need to display the number of people from individual countries on list.

I a have typical SQL query:

```
public function getAll(): array
    {
        $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM data ORDER by id DESC;');
        return $this->db->resultSet();
    }
```

but I don't know to how group my results :(

I print my result:

```
$this->model->getAll()
```

and then foreach....

In result I need:

```
1. 10 users from Poland; 
2. 101 users from Germany; 
3. 99 users from UK....
```

Please help me

Comment: Group by what? You need to give us a hint here.

Comment: I want show list: 1. 10 users from Poland; 2. 101 users from Germany; 3. 99 users from UK....

Comment: Sounds like `SELECT COUNT(*), country FROM data GROUP BY country`. With that you can render out the list in PHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be looking for simple aggregation:

```
select country, count(*) no_users from data group by country order by country;
```

This gives you two columns, with the country and the number of users. You can then generate the proper string output in your application.